# Compiler errors when using variables in an SQL statement

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am trying to code a logon process, but I get stuck when trying to execute an SQL statement containing variables that will come in from user input.

Here is how it looks:

```
Var 
  SS,temp,fn,sn: string;
Begin 
  ADO := TDBClass.Create('ICAdatabase.mdb');

  SS:= 'SELECT * FROM Agents Where aName = '  '  ' + fn + ' ' '  And aSurname = ' ' ' + sn +  ' ' ' ';

  Temp := Ado.processquery(SS);
End;
```

When I try to use variables like this, I get either "missing operator" or "semi-colon error" or "unterminated string".  Why is this?

Comment: Read about sql injection

Answer (score 5):

Your quote characters have extra spaces in between them that you need to remove.  `' ' '` is parsed differently than `'''`:

```
SS := 'SELECT * FROM Agents Where aName = ''' + fn + ''' And aSurname = ''' + sn + '''';
```

Alternatively, use `#39` instead of `''`:

```
SS := 'SELECT * FROM Agents Where aName = '#39 + fn + #39' And aSurname = '#39 + sn + #39;
```

Or use `QuotedStr()` or `AnsiQuotedStr()` instead:

```
SS := 'SELECT * FROM Agents Where aName = ' + QuotedStr(fn) + ' And aSurname = ' + QuotedStr(sn);
```

```
SS := 'SELECT * FROM Agents Where aName = ' + AnsiQuotedStr(fn, #39) + ' And aSurname = ' + AnsiQuotedStr(sn, #39);
```

Also, on a side note, you are leaking your `ADO` object, and you are not `Free`'ing it when done using it.

With that said, you really should stop building up the SQL statement manually at all.  Use a parameterized query instead (which is faster and safer).  I don't know what `TDBClass` is, but here is an example using `TADOQuery` instead:

```
var 
  fn, sn, temp: string;
Begin 
  fn := ...;
  sn := ...;

  Conn := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
  try
    Conn.ConnectionString := ...;

    ADO := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
    try
      ADO.Connection := Conn;

      ADO.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Agents Where aName = :AgentName And aSurname = :AgentSurname';

      ADO.Parameters.ParamValues['AgentName'] := fn;
      ADO.Parameters.ParamValues['AgentSurname'] := sn;

      ADO.Open;
      try
        if not (ADO.Bof and ADO.Eof) then
        begin
          // use ADO.Fields values as needed...
          Temp := ...;
        end;
      finally
        ADO.Close;
      end;
    finally
      ADO.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Conn.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Because your code is totally incorrect. You need to properly quote the variables. I'm not going to show you the wrong way to do it (by doubling up every single quote) which leads to a mess. I'll show you a somewhat better way that addresses the immediate question you asked, and then show you the proper way.

At a minimum, use QuotedStr - I'm not sure what `ADO.ProcessQuery` does or what `TDBClass` is, so I can't address that point. You should probably be using `TADOQuery` instead. You have to be very aware of what does and does not need to be quoted, and do all of the necessary data type conversions yourself. For instance, string values get quoted, numbers do not, and date values have to be manually converted to the format your database is expecting and quoted as well.

```
Var 
  SS,temp,fn,sn: string;
Begin 
  ADO := TDBClass.Create('ICAdatabase.mdb');
  SS:= 'SELECT * FROM Agents Where aName = '+ QuotedStr(fn) + 
       ' And aSurname = ' + QuotedStr(sn);
  Temp := Ado.processquery(SS);
End;
```

The proper way to do it is to use `TADOQuery` and parameters. The above code, in a real world example, would look more like this:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Agents WHERE aName = :Name';
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('AND aSurname = :Surname');
ADOQuery1.Params.ParamByName('Name').Value := SS;
ADOQuery1.Params.ParamByName('Surname').Value := SN;
ADOQuery1.Open;
```

This prevents all of the problems with quoting parameters, converting types (for instance, using a TDateTime directly), converting numbers and remembering not to quote them, etc., and also prevents SQL injection that can make your data vulnerable to malware or malevolent users.